# I am trying to get output of largest , smallest and the average of all inputs that I enter in python

Tags: python, average

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Write a program that prompts the user for integers. Once the user enters "done" output the largest, the smallest, and the average (sum/count). If the user enters anything other than an integer, then produce an error message.

This is my attempt:

```
largest = -1
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        n = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
            
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = n
    elif n < smallest:
        smallest = n 
    elif n > largest:
        largest = n
            
sum = 0
count = 0
sum += n
count+= 1
avg = sum/ count
            
print("Largest: ",largest)
print("Smallest: ",smallest)
print("average: ",avg)
```

However, I receive the following output:

```
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: done
Largest:  6
Smallest:  2
average:  6.0
```

Instead of the desired output:

```
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 6
Enter a number: done
Largest:  6
Smallest:  2
average:  4.0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236, and then make sure to **ask a question**. It should start with a question word like "why" or "how" and end with a question mark (`?`), and it should ask us for the specific thing that you need to know in order to solve the problem. To figure what to ask, you should start by understanding *what the actual problem is*. For example: when you run the code, what should happen? What does happen, and **how is that different**?

Comment: The next step is to [make your own attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [understand](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) why that problem occurs. If you can't figure it out yourself, then ask - making sure to explain how you tried to find the problem, your best guess about what is going wrong, and why you need help to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you only sum and count the last number that you received as input. You need the sum and the count variables to be inside of the while loop.

In addition, there are several things I would recommend changing:

- `sum` is a built-in function in python. Change that variable to a different name.
- Change the `except` to be more specific. In your case, change it to `except ValueError`. Having only `except` caches many other things, even a `KeyboardInterrupt`. See python's [exception hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).
- This could be considered a bit of nitpicking, but I would also change the prints to use python's f-strings. You can read about that [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).
- I would change `smallest` and `largest` implementation: Currently, if the user just enters "done" your code will print:

```
Largest: -1
Smallest: None
```

And then it will return an error as `n` was not yet defined:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

As this is not the desired behavior, you can change your code like so:

```
input_numbers = []

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        num_formatted = int(num)
        input_numbers.append(num_formatted)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
   
if not input_numbers:
    print("No numbers received")
else:
    max_input = max(input_numbers)
    min_input = min(input_numbers)
    average_input = sum(input_numbers) / len(input_numbers)

    print(f"Largest: {str(max_input)}")
    print(f"Smallest: {str(min_input)}")
    print(f"Average: {str(average_input)}")
```

So let's break this done:

- We create the list `input_numbers` to which we add each of the inputs numbers until we get the "done" input. We can then use the `min`, `max`, `sum`, and `len` functions to calculate what we need.
- If the list is empty, that means that the first input we got was "done" - so we print an appropriate message for this edge case.

As @Riccardo Bucco mentioned, the above solution takes an O(n) space, but it is possible to solve this problem using an `O(1)` space. I believe that in this case, saving the inputs is not that bad as the code is shorter and easier to understand. However, we can also do the following to achieve constant space complexity:

```
input_counter = 0
input_sum = 0
input_max = None
input_min = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        num_formatted = int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    
    # the code inside of this while loop is quite long, 
    # probably better to outsource this block to a seperate function
    if input_min is None:
        input_min = num_formatted
        input_max = num_formatted
    elif num_formatted < input_min:
        input_min = num_formatted
    elif num_formatted > input_max:
        input_max = num_formatted
    input_counter += 1
    input_sum += num_formatted
    
if not input_counter: # 0 is falsy in python, every other integer is truthy
    print("No numbers received")
else:
    average_input = input_sum / input_counter
    print(f"Largest: {str(input_max)}")
    print(f"Smallest: {str(input_min)}")
    print(f"Average: {str(average_input)}")
```

Comment: While this solution *does* work, please note that the space complexity is O(n) (it could be O(1), i.e. you don't need to memorize possibly thousands or millions of numbers to find out what's the minimum...). Also, by using `max`, `min` and `sum` you will look at every single number three more times (the time complexity is the same, but you still perform many useless operations).

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Thanks, I've updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible (commented) solution

```
largest = None
smallest = None

s = 0 # initialize before the loop, also avoid using 'sum' (it's a built-in function)
count = 0 # initialize before the loop

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        n = int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue # You need this command to go to the next loop iteration
        
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = n
        largest = n # don't forget to set the largest number too!
    elif n < smallest:
        smallest = n 
    elif n > largest:
        largest = n
    count += 1 # increment within the loop, every time you read a new number
    s += n # increment within the loop, every time you read a new number

if count != 0: # you don't want to divide by 0
    avg = s / count
```

Comment: You don't need `continue` in the except in order to go to the next iteration.

Comment: @EyalGolan What would you use to skip the conditionals then?

Comment: You're right, sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution :).

```
numbers = []
while True:
    num = input('Number: ')

    if num == 'done':
        break

    try:
        n = float(num)
        numbers.append(n)
    except:
        print('The input is not a number!')

smallest = None
largest = None
for n in numbers:
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = n 
        largest = n
    
    if n < smallest:
        smallest = n 
    elif n > largest:
        largest = n

average = largest - smallest

print(f'Smallest number: {smallest}')
print(f'Largest number: {largest}')
print(f'Average between numbers: {average}')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).